# How can I use FXML to specify the position of an overridden Node in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

I need to have a Gluon Glisten `View` object as the root node of any given Scene, because I'm using an `AppManager` and its `addViewFactory` method to control my application flow. I'd like to use Scene Builder to lay out the components of my application within the `View`. I'm able to use the following snippet to load the FXML file and extract the `View`:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(FXMLExtensibleView.class.getResource(String.format("fxml/%s.fxml", fxmlPath)));
View view = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
```

After doing this, I 'copy' the regions of the source `View` to my `extensibleView`:

```
setCenter(view.getCenter());
// repeated for top, left, right, and bottom.
```

`FXMLExtensibleView` is an abstract class extending `View`, so I can use this approach to override JavaFX behaviour as needed, but I'm not happy. This feels quite hacky, especially where it ends up copying over the children of the pure `View` object loaded from FXML.

Isn't there rather an 'upcasting' operation or the like that I could use to define a `View` in Scene Builder and then 'overwrite' that `View` with an implementation of my own that has custom behaviour as desired?

Comment: Need more details. At this stage I really don't get what is your `View` made up of. Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to accomplish.